# How to send message with nodemailer and email-templates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I try to send email with nodemailer and email-templates. Now I have example from here [example email templates](https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates/blob/master/examples/nodemailer/index.js). But when I check this code, I have error `a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Undefined]`

Help me please. This is my code

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var EmailTemplate = require('email-templates').EmailTemplate;

exports.sendOne = function () {
var templatesDir = config.templatesDir;
var template = new EmailTemplate(path.join(templatesDir, 'hello.jade'))
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: config.service,
    auth: config.auth
});

// An example users object with formatted email function
var locals = {
    email: 'example@mail.com',
    name: {
        first: 'Mamma',
        last: 'Mia'
    }
}

// Send a single email
template.render(locals, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err)
    }

    transport.sendMail({
        from: 'Spicy Meatball <spicy.meatball@spaghetti.com>',
        to: locals.email,
        subject: 'Mangia gli spaghetti con polpette!',
        html: results.html,
        text: results.text
    }, function (err, responseStatus) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err)
        }
        console.log(responseStatus.message)
    })
})

}
```

My error :

```
Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Undefined]
at /home/project/node_modules/email-templates/lib/util.js:31:39
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
From previous event: ...
```

Tell me please how to fix this error? thanks!

**UPDATE code**

```js
exports.sendOne = function () {
  var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

  var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "test@gmail.com",
      pass: "123456",
    },
  });

  var EmailTemplate = require("email-templates").EmailTemplate;
  var path = require("path");

  var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, "templates", "hello");

  var myTemplate = new EmailTemplate(templateDir);

  var locals = {
    email: "example@mail.com",
    name: {
      first: "Mamma",
      last: "Mia",
    },
  };

  myTemplate.render(locals, function (err, result) {
    // result.html
    // result.text
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }

    transport.sendMail(
      {
        from: "Spicy Meatball <spicy.meatball@spaghetti.com>",
        to: locals.email,
        subject: "Mangia gli spaghetti con polpette!",
        html: results.html,
        text: results.text,
      },
      function (err, responseStatus) {
        if (err) {
          return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log(responseStatus.message);
        return responseStatus; // return from status or as you need;
      }
    );
  });
};
```

I updated my code but now i have error `{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/path-to-my-project/templates/hello''] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'stat', path: '/path-to-my-project/templates/hello' }`

Comment: change this  `from: 'Spicy Meatball <spicy.meatball@spaghetti.com>',`  to  `from: ' "Spicy Meatball" <spicy.meatball@spaghetti.com>',`  here the problem with sender address

Comment: it is not working. Handler show error on `template.render(locals, function (err, results) {`

Comment: remove the extension `.jade` in the from `hello.jade` it should be just name like this `path.join(templatesDir, 'hello') and your `templatesDir` value should end with `/` otherwise url problems raise not found  
`

Comment: `var path = require('path')` add this line above the path variable usage

Comment: still not working, error `Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Undefined]`

Comment: I think you have to return some thing in the success function

Comment: you have to load your configuration file  `var config = require('./config');`

Comment: can u edit the question with the latest trials so that will be useful to answer ?

Comment: i updated code in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107759/discussion-between-john-ankanna-and-ennet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess template rendering issue and  you should `return` something from `function (err, responseStatus){}` for `success`

Here I assume `hello.jade` in `templates` folder and `templates` folder in `root directory` and ensure `jade` is using as template engine

can try it

```
var EmailTemplate = require('email-templates').EmailTemplate;
var path = require('path');

var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, 'templates', 'hello');

var myTemplate = new EmailTemplate(templateDir);
var locals = {
      email: 'example@mail.com',
      name: {
           first: 'Mamma',
           last: 'Mia'
      }
 }
myTemplate .render(locals , function (err, result) {
  // result.html 
  // result.text 
    if (err) {
       return console.error(err)
    }
    // check here what is showing in your result
    transport.sendMail({
        from: 'Spicy Meatball <spicy.meatball@spaghetti.com>',
        to: locals.email,
        subject: 'Mangia gli spaghetti con polpette!',
        html: results.html,
        text: results.text
     }, function (err, responseStatus) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err)
        }
        console.log(responseStatus.message)
        return responseStatus;// return from status or as you need;
    })
})
```

*Updated:* As far I guess it's not `nodemailer` related issue it's may be `template` rendering issue. can check by `directory` or by `html` page.

Comment: no, this is didnt help. error `a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Undefined]`

Comment: i updated my code https://jsfiddle.net/gb7jLjjx/1/  but i still have error `{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/path-to-my-project/templates/hello'']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/path-to-my-project/templates/hello' }` @shaishab roy

Comment: are you added `templates` folder in `path-to-my-project` folder and `hello.jade` file in `templates` folder: ?

Comment: yes, folder `templates` exists in my root project and it have file `hello.jade`

Comment: try my process without your `config.templatesDir` for `templateDir ` like `var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, 'templates', 'hello');
`

Comment: and my `result` return `undefined`

Comment: @ennet, I am also facing same issue and getting undefined values in result. I tried with directory path and file path also but got same error like "Error: Neither html nor text template files found or are both empty in path emails'

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the previous contributions I have been able to adapt *Nodemailer* with the current version of *email-emplates*

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const Email = require('email-templates');
const path = require('path');

//Nodemailer Transporter
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.mydomain.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: "noreply@mydomain.com",
        pass: "841%POHYRYK%",
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

//Generate template (Example: templates/emails/demo/index.pug)
var template = path.join(__dirname, 'templates/emails', 'demo');
var email = new Email({views: { root: template }});
var locals = {email:'myemail@gmail.com', username:'CompaCode'};

async function(){
    var html = await email.render(template, locals);

    //Send Email
    await transport.sendMail({from: 'Apolobit <noreply@apolobit.com>', to: locals.email, subject:'Demo Subject', html});
}
```